# Non unique object nhibernate c#

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I am working with c # and nhibernate in mysql, I have a list that stores sell products which at some point may be the same but different price.

Product A - Price 3.00
Product A - Price Two: 2.50

when wanting to save it shows me the following, which I'm sure is that nhibernate can not do that, if I am wrong please help me I need to solve this problem, thanks.

a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 72, of entity: DAL.Ent.Sale

also mention that my database if that income allows the same product at a different price because it has a unique identifier that makes them different.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the information that you have provided,  I would say that you need to look at the way your Domain objects are modeled.

You need to separate the product and the price of that product for a given store.  There needs to be a joining table in the middle to hold the relationship between a store, the product and the price of the product.  So that there is only one price for a product for a given store per record.

So you end up with something like this.

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
public class Price 
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Price> ProductPrices { get; set; }
}
```